# TwinCAT 3 visualisation: Button changes depending on state

Tags: visualization, plc, twincat

I am trying to implement a visualisation to control my PLC with a Touchscreen. I want to create a button which description changes depending of the state of the button.
Example: At the beginning the Buttons says 'start'; after it is pressed it should say 'stop'.

Can anybody tell me how to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will advise against changing the functionality of your touchscreen buttons on the fly. It is better to have two separate buttons, always defined as 'Stop' and  'Start'.

If you do insist on using the same button, the button text follows the same formatting rules as a text field, i.e. you can link it to a text variable in your PLC program as described in the TwinCAT3 Visualization Help.

Answer (score 0):

Under "Properties" of the button, under "Texts > Text", type in "%s".
Under "Text Variables > Text Variable", type in the PLC variable, e.g. "MAIN.sDescription"

Change the value of MAIN.sDescription to be "Start" or "Stop"